# Using WMI to Determine which adapter(s) is connected to the internet

Tags: vbscript, network-programming, wmi

I am writing a VB Script that uses WMI to determine which adapter is used for internet connectivity?  For example - if I have a LAN and a 3G board it needs to tell the user which is connected.  I understand that a machine might have >1 internet connection, but for now, let's assume 1.

edit:
Ok, how can I do this using any command tool?  Given the roaring silence, I guess this is not do-able using WMI.  :-)  Would trace print work?  I'm not too familiar with trace.

Thanks in advance for any help! 
Rich

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using **Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration** find the network device that has the lowest **IPConnectionMetric**, this will be the first device used for internet access.

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject(_
    "winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration")

metric = 500
description = ""

For Each objItem in colItems
    If (objItem.IPConnectionMetric < metric AND objItem.IPConnectionMetric >= 0) then
        metric = objItem.IPConnectionMetric
        description = objItem.Description
    End If
Next

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Popup(description)
```

VBScript examples for accessing the WMI can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394595(v=VS.85).aspx)